# camera2 api -> mediaCodec -> mediaMuxer -> mp4 file

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm trying to get an mp4 file. I shoot video using the camera2 api and can save this as an avc file using MediaCodec. But I do not understand how I can redo this code, for encoding into an mp4 file using MediaMuxer. Sorry for my English, this is translated through a translator

```
private class EncoderCallback : MediaCodec.Callback() {

      override fun onInputBufferAvailable(codec: MediaCodec, index: Int) {
      }
      override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(
          codec: MediaCodec,
          index2: Int,
          info: MediaCodec.BufferInfo
      ) {
          outPutByteBuffer = mCodec!!.getOutputBuffer(index2)
          val outDate = ByteArray(info.size)
           outPutByteBuffer!![outDate]
          try {
              Log.i("EncoderCallBack", " outDate.length : " + outDate.size)

              outputStream!!.write(outDate, 0, outDate.size) 
          } catch (e: IOException) {
              e.printStackTrace()
          }
          mCodec!!.releaseOutputBuffer(index2, false)
      }

      override fun onError(codec: MediaCodec, e: MediaCodec.CodecException) {
          Log.i("EncoderCallBack", "Error: $e")
      }

      override fun onOutputFormatChanged(codec: MediaCodec, format: MediaFormat) {
          Log.i("EncoderCallBack", "encoder output format changed: $format")
      }

  }
```

after initializing MediaCodec, I record the video:

```
var texture: SurfaceTexture = textureViewOver
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(320, 240)
     surface = Surface(texture)   
builder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
          builder.addTarget(surface)
          builder.addTarget(mEncoderSurface!!)

          mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
              mutableListOf(surface, mEncoderSurface),
              object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {...
```

Comment: Are you using `OnImageAvailableListener` or `Surface`?

Comment: This code is unreadable as a comment, could you edit a question?

Comment: added the code.
I ran into the problem that some samsung devices have problems recording videos after going to sleep mode. A very long first frame is recorded. I found a way to fix this with ffmpeg, but I have to rewrite the video and it takes time. Because of this, I want to try using MediaCodec instead of MediaRecorder

Answer (score 0):

the muxer code is missing:

```
 override fun onOutputBufferAvailable(
      codec: MediaCodec,
      index2: Int,
      info: MediaCodec.BufferInfo
  ) {
      outPutByteBuffer = mCodec!!.getOutputBuffer(index2)
      mediaMuxer?.writeSampleData(trackIndex, outPutByteBuffer, info)
      mCodec!!.releaseOutputBuffer(index2, false)
  }
```